# Is it possible to add an empty column with no values in the beginning of a .CSV file?

Tags: linux, unix, csv, sed, awk

How do I add an empty column at the beginning of a .CSV file using **`awk`**? I am trying the following code, but that doesn't help.

```
awk '{",",print $0}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{print ","$0}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

or

```
awk '{$0=","$0}1' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '{printf ","; print $0}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Or:

```
awk '{printf(",%s\n", $0)}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/,/' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach it to set the output field separator then print a leading empty field:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{print "", $0}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you only want to add a comma at the *beginning* of a csv file and not at the beginning of every line.

```
awk '{ if (NR==1) printf "," ;print $0 }' a.csv > b.csv
```

Comment: Actually, my bad... I should have put my question in a more clearer way... I needed a blank column in the complete file or to be more specific a blank value in the beginning of every record. If I wanted only one comma in front of the first records, your solution is perfect. Thanks bsd...